# HTML makes Google Chrome Icon in task bar and tab blink, and send desktop notification

Tags: javascript, html, browser, push-notification, notifications

I am building a web app when the user finds a match, the app will deliver notifications to the user. I wish to deliver three different kinds of notifications. I am not sure if it can be achieved with HTML or JavaScript.

When there is a match:

1) The browser icon in the task bar will flash orange, like shown in the picture below (but for the Google Chrome icon):
[image]

2) The tab at which my web app is open at will have a favicon color change and displays a message: "matched." An example I can think of is Omegle:

[image]

3) The web app will deliver a desktop notification similar to how Slack does it
[image]

Any help and advice are very appreciated.

Comment: To add a message to the top of the tab, the following javascript can be used:
`document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML = "newMessage";`